# actionlib tutorial inconsistency

Tags: ros, actionlib-tutorials, actionlib

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The [SimpleActionServer(ExecuteCallbackMethod) tutorial](http://www.ros.org/wiki/actionlib_tutorials/Tutorials/SimpleActionServer%28ExecuteCallbackMethod%29) has a CMakeList.txt inconsistency for Catkin/Groovy.

At one place it says:

> find_package(catkin REQUIRED
> COMPONENTS actionlib_msgs) Note that
> **CMake needs to find_package only
> actionlib_msgs** (not message_generation
> that is referenced implicitly by
> actionlib_msgs).

Later it says:

> find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS actionlib message_generation)

I assume the second one was not updated and the first example is correct. Please confirm.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/52386/actionlib-tutorial-inconsistency/) by [Dave Coleman](https://answers.ros.org/users/1279/dave-coleman/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1396 on 2013-01-15

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You're right. The following should be correct. I updated the wiki. Thank you for reporting!

```
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS actionlib_msgs)
```

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2013-01-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I fixed this in the tutorial. Basically the snippets at the top where up-to-date. So I updated the complete CMakeLists.txt at the end to be identical.

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2013-01-15

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1